# How to keep divs with border inside a fixed contained side by side

Tags: css

Setting width on both divs less than 50% does not cut because a small gap is created between.

https://jsfiddle.net/54u543e5/

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="a"></div>
    <div id="b"></div>
</div>

#container {
    width: 50%;
}

#b {
    width: 50%;
    height: 1.5rem;
    background-color: black;
    float: right;
    border-top: 0.2rem solid red;
    border-right: 0.2rem solid red;
}

#a {
    width: 50%;
    height: 1.5rem;
    background-color: grey;
    float: left;
    border-top: 0.2rem solid blue;
    border-left: 0.2rem solid blue;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that, by default, `width` does not include borders. So if you use `width: 50%`, the total width will be `50% + 0.2rem`,  which is greater than `50%`.

Therefore, you can:

- Use `width: calc(50% - 0.2rem)`, so that the total width will be `50% - 0.2rem + 0.2rem`, that is, exactly `50%`

  ```css
  #container {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .item {
    width: calc(50% - 0.2rem);
    height: 1.5rem;
    background-color: black;
    float: right;
    border: solid red;
    border-width: 0.2rem 0.2rem 0 0;
  }
  .item + .item {
    background-color: grey;
    float: left;
    border-color: blue;
    border-width: 0.2rem 0 0 0.2rem;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <div id="container">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
  ```
- Use `box-sizing: border-box`. This will make `width` include the borders.

  ```css
  #container {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .item {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 50%;
    height: 1.5rem;
    background-color: black;
    float: right;
    border: solid red;
    border-width: 0.2rem 0.2rem 0 0;
  }
  .item + .item {
    background-color: grey;
    float: left;
    border-color: blue;
    border-width: 0.2rem 0 0 0.2rem;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <div id="container">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
  ```

Comment: Both amazing solutions, specialty calc. Opens a world of possibilities!